# Trying to get an average from a dictionary of results

Tags: python, average

For this code I am trying to get the overall average of a class. I would open the file and then remove all characters and line strips from the dictionary to get only the scores of each pupil. I then try to get the sum of the file and then divide it by the length but am getting an error.

```
average = (sum(file)/len(file))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

here is the code:

```
    with open('classtwo.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
        newfile = (str.strip("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z") for str in csv_file if str.strip("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z"))
        file = [line.strip() for line in newfile if line.strip()]
        average = (sum(file)/len(file))
        print(average)
```

Anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: This is IMHO not a duplicate: The error is the same, but this question gets the error implicitly via the `sum` function.

Comment: You don't need all those commas in the `str.strip()` call..

Comment: @HannesOvrén: agreed, re-hammered it to a question with the same error message using `sum()`.

Comment: Avoid using a variable named `file` or you will 'shadow' the builtin `file` method which could result in unwanted/hard to debug errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` is a list of strings. The `sum` function expects a number.
To get an average you should convert each entry in `file` to a number:

e.g. `file = [float(x) for x in file]`